# Exception Handling in SCSF

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, exception

I have a SCSF application i am trying to handle most of the exceptions using

`Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(new ThreadExceptionHandler().ApplicationThreadException);`

The event handler :-

```
public class ThreadExceptionHandler
    {
        public void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Exception.Message, "An exception occurred:", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
```

Works fine . I can catch all the application exceptions in this block.

But the problem is after handling the exception the code again goes and executes the same exception generating code again. This happens till the time I get a windows message windows  to send the error info to microsoft.

Could any one please help in telling me where I might be going wrong.

Thanks in Advance

Vikram

Note :-  Currently i am throwing 
New Exception("Test Exception"); from a button event. I am doing this to provide event handling in my application.

Comment: You'll need to document what kind of code is throwing the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some banging my head against the code I found that the problem was due to the fact that my SCSF solution had a winforms Shell and on that shell there were WPF usercontrols.

When the exception where generated on these WPF usercontrol (mostly the case) they are not caught by 
Application.ThreadException coz Application class for WPF is different than that for Winforms.

In WPF application one need to handle Application.DispacherUnhandledException event.

Just my little finding ...

Answer (score 2):

You have to set

```
Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);
```

See [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.threadexception.aspx) for example code

But note that this kind of catch-all exception handling is not a good *replacement* for exception handling inside your logic. It is a good backup, but the best thing to do in a global handler is to log the information and exit. Your app could be in an unsafe/undefined state.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)

In my main code block for test i have put both appdomain AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(AppDomainUnhandledException);

and 

Application.ThreadException += new ThreadExceptionEventHandler(Application_ThreadException);

But now i find that thread exception event is not getting fired.
I have also set Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException);

Answer (score 0):

you would be surprised by just handling the Application.DispatcherUnhandledException. I have worked with SCSF which had WPF user controls. Read through this post . http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/c57cac13-f960-49a1-94b5-a3fd316ac4bc/ i would recommend handling AppDomain.UnhandledException too.